# Communication between synchronous and asynchronous points

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

I have three elements in my scenario:
**A** = browser
**B** = J2EE server listening for Websockets and simple GET requests
**C** = Java application connected to B with websockets

A makes GET request to B (synchronously), B sends Websocket message which holds request information, C responds back (asynchronously) and B should send back the response within the SAME context/request/thread as on the beginning.

```
A                       B                                 C
| ---- GET request ---> | ----- Websocket message ------> |
|                       | <---- Websocket response ------ |
| <---- response -----  |
```

My question is, how could I stop the GET request on the left side while waiting for the response from C. Can B act as an intermediary point between those synchronous/asynchronous elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me, and works like a charm. https://github.com/mejmo/async2sync

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do something like "long polling" on your B side.
Look at [Implementing long polling in an asynchronous fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081895/implementing-long-polling-in-an-asynchronous-fashion)