# Http servlet not returning any value

Tags: java, servlets

HttpServletResponse is not returning any value when I use it with the Scheduler. In the following code till "RETURNED" its printing in the console. But the next line which is out.println(previousLastLine) is not returning. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(value="/notifyController")
public class NotificationController extends HttpServlet{

    int rep = 0;
    String previousTime = null;
    String previousLastLine = null; 
    String lastText = null;
    int count = 0;
    boolean changeFlag = false;
    final long timeInterval = 1000;
    HttpServletResponse response = null;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response = resp;
        if(rep == 0){
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        changeFlag = scheduleTask(); 
                        if(changeFlag == true){
                            try {
                                System.out.println("RETURNED");
                                response.setContentType("text/html");
                                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                                out.println(previousLastLine);
                                out.flush();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(timeInterval);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            rep++;
        }
    }

    public boolean scheduleTask(){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/messagedetails.txt"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(lastText != sCurrentLine){
                    lastText = sCurrentLine;
                }
            }
            if(count == 1 && !previousLastLine.equalsIgnoreCase(lastText)){
                previousLastLine = lastText;
                return true;
            }
            previousLastLine = lastText;
            count = 1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an exception in the logs?

Comment: Are you trying to implement long polling ? If so you're missing the asyn attribute in your @WebServlet annotation. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081895/implementing-long-polling-in-an-asynchronous-fashion

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to set the response type and write the response body using a background thread.  That is not going to work in a `doPost` method.

The problem is that when the `doPost` call returns, the servlet framework is going to immediately "commit" the response with an empty body.  When the `run()` method of your background thread tries to call `setContentType` on the response object, it will throw an exception.

You are catching `IOException`, but I'm pretty sure that the exception that is thrown is an unchecked exception.  (If you check the logfiles, you might see the exception stacktrace there.)

If you are trying to implement asynchronous behavior of some kind, then you need to be using a Servlet 3.0 spec compliant container, and you need to code your servlet differently.

Reference:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm