# AWS Elastic BeansTalk Nginx Timeout 504 Bad Gateway - Java Servlet AsyncContext

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, servlets, nginx

I have successfully ran tests of a java servlet app that runs on the base sample app provided by Amazon AWS Elastic BeansTalk. Java-Gradle-Jetty Platform.
Now I can't achieve to keep the servlet connected more than 50 seconds with the client no matter what I do.
Things I tried.
Nginx
proxy_read_timeout works!
proxy_send_timeout doesn't work.
Load Balancer Idle Timeout Does work..
keepalive_timeout doesn't work.

I have played around with these and a few more settings so I'm getting familiar and can restrict or bump the time outs but only to 50 seconds. Passed that I get a 504 Bad Gateway error which means connection was closed.
I also get this error in the error.log for the nginx server.
{sometime} [error] 23115#0: *2 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: {Some IP}, server: , request: "GET /{some path} HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/publish", host: "{Some Load Balancer URL}.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com"

Any help will be appreciated I've spent a few sleepless nights now.

Comment: here's the link of the code I used for reference. [link_to_code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081895/implementing-long-polling-in-an-asynchronous-fashion)

Answer (score 2):

it ended up being two properties that needed to be passed on the nginx configuration file under the location section.

proxy_send_timeout
and
proxy_read_timeout

just set them to whatever time you wanna have in seconds in combination with the ELB (Load Balancer) timeout.

hope it's useful for someone.

Comment: also, everytime you deploy through the Elastic Beans Talk the configuration files get overwritten.

Comment: is there a place in my `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` I could put a line for this? I've been investigating for the better part of a day where it's dead ending, and there's no setting in the elasticbeanstalk config for the env or at the ELB level and was hoping you could shed some light on where I could add these config settings

Comment: In my case I was using AWS RDS and the inbound rules for the security group were only set to my home ip. After deploying the app to EBS it kept timing out. So changing the inbound rules to 0.0.0.0/0 fixed the timeout issue.